# Nodejs Missing Data From HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fs

I am currently trying to get a file from a HTTP request and then write the data to a file (in this case a PDF).

Using the following I can generate a valid PDF but the file I send has a few lines but the file I create is blank.

The function I am using to try and get the data:

```
async function getDataFromReq(req){
    let body = '';
    await req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
    });
    return body;
}
```

My implementation of that function and writing it to a file:

```
let file = await getDataFromReq(req);
await writeFile(fileName,file);
```

My write file function:

```
async function writeFile(fileName,file){
    fs.writeFileSync('./'+fileName, file);
}
```

Note:

I was able to use King Friday's solution but I took Quentins's advice and used existing libraries to do the task instead of reinventing the wheel. I used multer following this guide - https://bezkoder.com/node-js-express-file-upload/

Comment: I don't think `req.on()` returns a Promise. You can create your own, and `resolve(body)` inside `req.on('end' ...)`

Comment: The function `writeFile` also doesn't need to be a async function as `fs.writeFileSync` is synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Like so

```
const { promises as fs } = require('fs');

function getDataFromReq(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
      body += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
      resolve(body);
    });
    req.on('error', err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
});
```

Then you can use in an async method like so...

```
const body = await getDataFromReq(req);
await fs.writeFile(fileName, body);
```

Comment: I implemented your code so thank you. Unfortunately I still seem to be getting the same issue. The PDF just comes out blank but some meta information is there such as author. Is there something else I am doing that could be at fault?

Comment: @Niall you should go here -> codesandbox.io and choose a node sandbox, then you can put your code and collaborate, meaning i could take a look and tweak. I really like their service.

Comment: @Niall also take a look here relating to fs -> https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Comment: @Niall i adjusted, may help, see the compatible fs promises reference for node v10 +.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to use your solution but ended up using multer which was a lot tidier and easier to use

Comment: @Niall that's probably a good call. You'll find there are a lot of great npm packages out there as you go. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

- You can only usefully await a promise
- `req.on` does not return a promise

You need to:

1. Get rid of `await` inside `getDataFromReq`
2. Get rid of `async` from the declaration of `getDataFromReq` (it is pointless unless you use `await` inside it)
3. Explicitly return a `new Promise` from `getDataFromReq`
4. Register a handler for when the incoming data has finished coming in (`req.on('end', ...`).
5. `resolve` the promise inside that handler

However, it would probably be easier to not reinvent wheels. There are already promise based modules for [reading files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-readfile-promise) and [making HTTP requests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to King Friday's answer above, what helped me in getting a pdf file from an HTTP request was adding this line in the `event` `'data'`:

```
body += Buffer.from(chunk).toString('base64');
```

Before, I was instead collecting the request information in an array and converting the body in the end function to a base64 string. That was giving me the same result, a blank pdf. However, switching it to be a string, and concatenating the chunks of data while also converting each chunk to a base64 string fixed the problem. Full code example:

```
function getPdfFromRequest(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
      body += Buffer.from(chunk).toString('base64');
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
      resolve(body);
    });
    req.on('error', err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
});
```

**Update:**
The previous solution I recorded above worked only for a pdf that is one page. To solve this issue, instead I changed `body` to be an `array`, and in the `data` callback, I am going through the `buffer` object and adding each value to the `body` array. Finally, in the `end` function I am converting the `buffer` array to a `base64` string.

```
function getPdfFromRequest(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const body = [];
    req.on('data', chunk => {
      chunk.forEach((data) => body.push(data));
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
      resolve(Buffer.from(body).toString('base64'));
    });
    req.on('error', err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
});
```